# How to rotate labels using bar_label in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

1. How do I rotate the labels by 90 degree in a bar chart using `matplotlib.bar_label()`? [image]
2. In the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html) of `matplotlib.bar_label()`, can you explain usage of below argument with some example?

> **kwargs: Any remaining keyword arguments are passed through to Axes.annotate.

```
#CODE TO PRODUCE ABOVE SHOWN CHART

labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
men_means = [20, 34, 30, 35, 27]
women_means = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(x, labels)
ax.legend()   

ax.bar_label(rects1, labels=["ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC"], padding=3, label_type='center')
ax.bar_label(rects2, labels=["DEF","DEF","DEF","DEF","DEF"], padding=3, label_type='center')

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Well, `bar_label()` sends all parameters that it doesn't use towards [`annotate()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html). On its turn, `annotate()` sends unprocessed parameters to [`text()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text).  One of these parameters is `rotation`.  So, one example could be `ax.bar_label(....., rotation=90)`